# Dirac Delta Function by M.S. Howe

Tags: acoustics, dirac-delta-distributions

I'm reading 'Hydrodynamics and Sound' by M.S. Howe. I want to understand the point source like the figure. I could understand $\nabla^2\phi=0$, if $r>0$. But I couldn't understand $r\rightarrow 0$ situation. The book assumes the solution is
$$\phi = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{-q(t)}{4\pi(r^2+\epsilon^2)^\frac{1}{2}}, \epsilon>0$$
then
$$\nabla^2\phi=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{3\epsilon^2q(t)}{4\pi(r^2+\epsilon^2)^\frac{5}{2}}$$
But I couldn't understand what $(r^2+\epsilon^2)$ means. Especially what $\epsilon$ indicates in the figure. Would you explain me about it?

**<<<<UPDATE<<<<<**

I could understand the meaning of $\epsilon$. Without $\epsilon$, we cannot consider the situation $r=0$. But if we use $\epsilon$, we can consider the situation at $r=0$. Above $\phi$ equation satisfies $\nabla^2\phi=0 @r\neq0$ and $\nabla^2\phi=\infty @r=0$. It means,

if $r\neq0$,
$$\nabla^2\phi=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{3\epsilon^2q(t)\times\epsilon^{-2}}{4\pi(r^2+\epsilon^2)^\frac{5}{2}\times\epsilon^{-2}}=\frac{3q(t)}{\infty}=0$$
if $r=0$,
$$\nabla^2\phi=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{3q(t)}{4\pi\epsilon^3}=\frac{3q(t)}{0}=\infty$$
Additionally, it also follows the flow rate. If we take the volume integral including the origin,
$$\int_V\nabla^2\phi dV=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_V\frac{3\epsilon^2q(t)}{4\pi(r^2+\epsilon^2)^\frac{5}{2}}dV=q(t)\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{3\epsilon^2}{4\pi(r^2+\epsilon^2)^\frac{5}{2}}dV$$
$$=q(t)\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{3\epsilon^2r^2}{(r^2+\epsilon^2)^\frac{5}{2}}dr=q(t)$$
I cannot derive third equal and fourth equal of the last equation. Would you explain me about it?

[image]

Comment: *I couldn't understand what $(r^2+\epsilon^2)$ means.* What about the sum of two squares don’t you understand? Do you understand $c^2=a^2+b^2$ in the Pythagorean Theorem?

Comment: I think my explanation was not good. So I edited my question.

Comment: Where do you see $r$ goes to zero? The equations you wrote only have $\epsilon$ going to zero. I feel like there is more to this problem.

Comment: That was my misunderstanding. To allow $r=0$, $\epsilon$ is introduced. So $r$ doesn't goes to zeros. I'll edit later soon.

Answer (score 1):

In problems like this (in this case with a zero division) when we are looking at the behavior of things like "point sources" or whatever, we need to deal with the zero denominator and infinite level (at the point). Since the differential equations can't handle this, what is done is the size is set to a small, nonzero number (e.g. $\epsilon$) and the problem is solved. Then, the limit is taken as $\epsilon$ approaches zero. If the limiting behavior exists, it is taken to be the behavior of the ideal "point source" or whatever.

In this problem, what is being studied is the behavior at $r$, a finite location, from a "point source" of sound. It is solved by using an "$\epsilon$ source" of sound, finding the behavior at $r$, and then letting $\epsilon$ approach $0$.

This is similar in principle to the motivation behind the definition of the derivative.

In physics, the study of these idealized "point sources" is usually done with an object called the Dirac $\delta$ [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), which can conceptually be thought of a function that is zero everywhere except x = zero, where it is "infinity" so that it integrates to one.

Comment: Maybe I could understand partly. If $\epsilon$ is not used, we can consider $\lim_{r\to 0}$, but we cannot consider $r=0$, because it will be infinite. But if we add $\epsilon$, we can consider the situation $r=0$. Is this correct?

Comment: I would have to see the problem in the book, but I read this as $r$ is the *location of the receiver* that is hearing the sound. You want to know what the receiver hears from a "point" source. You do this by considering a finite source $\epsilon$ and then letting that source get arbitrarily small.

Answer (score 0):

$\epsilon$ is to avoid inifinity before it goes to zero. This can be understood by taking integral of this function with another function

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. First, I edited my question since it was too simple and didn't deliver my question correctly. And I still couldn't understand $\epsilon$. if $\lim_{r\to 0} $and $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} $, can you solve it?

Comment: $r$ is not going to zero, it is the location being studied. $\epsilon$ will go to zero because it is a point source.

Comment: $\epsilon$ may not have a physical meaning. It could be just mathematic trick to avoid infinity. You could use this finite version to do the calculation. Only at the last step, let $\epsilon$ goes to zero.